# How to make Contact Form 7 messages appear in a pop-up box?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact Form 7 plugin for Wordpress and I would like to show both the "Validation errors ocurred" and "Message sent sucessfully" messages in a pop-up box instead of a text in the page (because this last option would ruin the elements position).

I understand I have to use the Additional Settings box, but what is the code to do it? I've tried the following for the sucessful message:

```
on_sent_ok: "alert('Your message here!');"
```

But it doesn't seem to work. And I've no idea what's the code for the validation errors message.

Comment: That works fine for me I just tested it. Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I get no errors, it simply doesn't work. Check out the page yourself if you want:  [link](http://inpabol.com/contato-2). I can't figure out what's wrong.